# Validate a field using PHP so that it won't advance to another page?

Tags: php, validation

I wonder how to validate fields in html form using PHP so that when I click the button "submit", it won't advance to another page before all field is valid?

Comment: PHP runs server-side - you'd need to validate the form with Javascript.

Comment: use javascript for frontend like jquery validator plugin .. php used for server side scripting

Comment: As a clarification, do you mean "don't load a new page at all" or "don't load a new page if the validation fails"?  Based on comments and answers, we aren't really sure which. I thought it was the 2nd one, in which case using server-side validation would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this checks if the submit button or the name you've given in the submit button is set
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //getting the html element name to the variable $name
    $name=$_POST['name'];

        //do your validation here
        if($name==''){// this checks if the $name field is null or empty
            // error alert user
        }else{
            // do your required tasks here or simply add an else if 
            // and check for another validation
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an if statement on the server side, something along the lines of...

```
if($POST['txt'] != ''){
    // validation successful, redirect user
}
else
{
    // validation failed, alert user
}
```

Comment: This solution will not meet all OP's criteria as it will reload the page, the only way is to use javascript to achieve his goal

Comment: @LemuelBotha he said not advance to another page, for all we know there is a page1.php page2.php page3.php, he also asked for a php solution, but thanks for the downvote, what has stack overflow become...